# Laravel tinyInteger primary key with incrementation

Tags: laravel, migration, primary-key, auto-increment

I am trying to add via script primary keys and I have variables which says if it's primary key and if it is inc. The problem is that I can't find a way to easily define the primary key that increments.

With this migration Laravel only adds primary key, but it isn't inremented:

```
$table->tinyInteger('taxable')->primary();
```

this only added primary key without incrementation

---

```
$table->tinyInteger('taxable')->primary()->increments();
```

Didn't add auto-inc.

---

```
$table->tinyInteger('taxable', true);
```

Tried this method which instantly applies primary key and auto-inc, but I want it to be flexible for my script. (I don't want that it would add primary key and auto-inc both instantly I want to define it myself).

So I tried different variations but none of them gave me the result I wanted - to easily define if it is a primary key and if it is auto-incremented.

```
  $table->tinyInteger('taxable', true, true);
  $table->tinyInteger('taxable', false, true);
  $table->tinyInteger('taxable', true, false);
  $table->tinyInteger('taxable', false, false);
```

It seems that the second false doesn't do anything at all and I thought the first true - defines if it is primary key and the second true if it is auto-incremented.

---

I found the best solution for me (*because I wanted to find an easy way to define primary keys in my script*):

```
$table->tinyInteger('taxable')->autoIncrement(); //Adds primary key and auto-inc
$table->tinyInteger('taxable')->primary(); //adds just primary key
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to define it myself"?

Comment: Like I tried to explain that I am writing a script and it would be easier for me to find a way to define primary keys and their auto-inc in a simple way, for example **IF IT WORKED but it doesn't**:

`$table->tinyInteger('taxable', true, false);`

It would ease my scripting if I could define primary keys like that. First **true** - defines if it is a primary key and the second - defines if it is auto-inc. I hope I made it clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a special increments method in migrations:

```
$table->tinyIncrements('id');
```